# Removing RepresentedFilename From Window Through NSWindowController

Tags: swift, cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

[image]

I understand that we can set a respresented file name with a generic icon to the window (`NSWindow`) through a window controller (`NSWindowController`).

```
class MyWindowController: NSWindowController {
    @objc func setTitleFileName(notification: NSNotification) {
        // myWindow is an IBOutlet object to a window (`NSWindow`), path is a file path
        if let path = notification.object as? String {
            myWindow.setTitleWithRepresentedFilename(path)
        }
    }
}
```

So I get a file name (Test.mov) as a represented file name.  I set a file in one view controller (`NSViewController`).  When the application transitions to another, I want to remove it and set the application name back.  But it doesn't look like I can remove it.  If I just set a string to the window like

```
myWindow.title = "Application"
```

, the generic icon will still remain.  I cannot set nil to `setTitleWithRepresentedFilename`.  Is there any way by which I can remove the generic file icon once it's done?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myWindow.representedFilename = ""
```

or

```
myWindow.setTitleWithRepresentedFilename("")
```

will remove the icon.

Comment: An empty file path...  Why didn't I think about it?  Thanks.